# How do you create a javascript result div that must change according to the $ID

Tags: javascript

I have a page which has boxes that get added dynamically and associated with an ID in the database. You click on a + to add the box or a remove box link to drop it. This works fine. Within each box are some fields that the administrator will complete, name, email, etc. I set up an ajax save so that as you enter data it saves (saveData.js pointing to url: saveData.php). That works.

Each box has a result div created with the id:

```
<div id="result<?php $id; ?></div>
```

It looks like:

It passes an ID, name, some other stuff to the save script via the datastring. If I set up a html result I need to make it dynamic so that the resuls shows up in the correct box. It is set up like:

```
$(document).on('mouseout','.saveData',function()
{
  var DATA=$(this).val();
  var data=plus(escape(DATA));
  var ID=$(this).attr('id');
  var NAME=$(this).attr('name');
  $("#result").html( "" );

  var dataString = 'first_name='+ data +'&id='+ ID;
```

And the post:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "templates/saveData.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    { 
      $("#result").html( html );
    } 
  });
})
```

What I need to do is to modify the code so that result is result-$ID meaning result-21, result-22, etc.

I added a variable with the ID:

```
var RESULT = result- +  ID;
```

Then substituting the RESULT variable into the div, changing

```
$("#result").html( "" );
```

to

```
$("#$RESULT").html( "" );
```

and in the ajax:

```
$("#result").html( html );
```

to

```
$("#$RESULT").html( html );
```

This does not work. How is this done?

Comment: Let's start with the first mistake: `var RESULT = result- +  ID;` is supposed to be `var RESULT = "result-" + ID;`

Comment: I would do some more research into how string concatenation works. Right now, your code is looking for an element with an ID of `$RESULT`, not substituted. If you want string substitution like that, you'll need to look into [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Comment: I changed to: var RESULT = "result-" + ID; I get that. Then I changed in the other two instances of #result to: `$("#${RESULT}").html( "" );` and `$("#${RESULT}").html( html );`  I found the brackets on the template literals page but this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

In your PHP you can join it like:

```
$joined = $_POST["first_name"] . "-" . $_POST["id"];
```

That will give you: "name-21"...

In JavaScript that would be:

var joined = first_name + "-" + id;

Comment: I know that I can do this in php but I don't see how it helps solve the problem with #result in the javascript file.